# Java float formatting issue

Tags: java, formatting

I retrieve from an XML file a float number that I want to format and insert in a text file with the pattern 8 digits after comma, and 2 before.

Here is my code:

```
String patternNNDotNNNNNNNN = "%11.8f";
float value = 1.70473711f;
String result = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, patternNNDotNNNNNNNN, value);
System.out.println(result);
```

As a result I get: 1.704737**07**

Same problem if I use:

```
java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols(java.util.Locale.US);
java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("##.########", symbols);
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

I don't understand why I have a rounded value (1.704737**11** comes to 1.704737**07**).

Comment: Floats have limited precision. See what happens with a double. (of course doubles have limited precision too, but they have more than a float)

Comment: [How many significant digits do floats and doubles have in java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13542944)

Comment: Related, with lots of relevant links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the *precision* of the `float` means that the value `1.7043711` is not actually `1.7043711`.

Consider the following which process `1.70473711f` as both a `float` and a `double`:

```
String patternNNDotNNNNNNNN = "%11.8f";

float valueF = 1.70473711f;
String result = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, patternNNDotNNNNNNNN, valueF);
System.out.println(valueF);
System.out.println(result);

double valueD = 1.70473711f;
result = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, patternNNDotNNNNNNNN, valueD);
System.out.println(valueD);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
1.7047371
 1.70473707
1.7047370672225952
 1.70473707
```

When treating the value as a double, you can see that `1.7043711f` is actually `1.7047370672225952`.  Rounding that to 8 places gives `1.70473707` and *not* `1.70473711` as expected.

Instead, treat the number as a double (i.e. remove the `f`) and the increase precision will result in the expected output:

```
double valueD = 1.70473711;
String result = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, patternNNDotNNNNNNNN, valueD);
System.out.println(valueD);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
1.70473711
 1.70473711
```

Comment: Many thanks for this clear answer. it comes from the float precision. i will convert it as a double. Thanks !

Comment: @nicolasviala You're welcome.  Please remember to upvote any useful answers and mark one as correct if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: How can I do this (upvote a useful comment)?

Comment: @nicolasviala Use the Up Arrow next to each answer.  Also put a tick on the one that is the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

`String.format` on floating point values *does* round them. If you don't want that, use `BigDecimal`. See

```
double d = 0.125;
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);
```